# Can you disable the React-Admin Undo feature in config?

Tags: react-admin

The Undo feature is a great, but it can cause inefficiencies during development cycles.

Is there an easy way for us to disable it in our staging environment, or at least lower the timeout?

Answer (score 7):

The Edit and Create components support the undoable parameter. So you could do like this `<Edit {...props} undoable={false} >` to disable the undo function for a specific Form

Answer (score 1):

When I unterstand the documentation and src correctly, you have to override the notification component in order to change the `autoHideDuration`.
This is the time the notification is visible to the user and after the delay, the request is send to the api.

When you set it to `0` the requests should be send nearly immediately.
From the [documentation - Theming - Notifications](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html):

> You can override the notification component, for instance to change
>   the notification duration. It defaults to 4000, i.e. 4 seconds, and
>   you can override it using the autoHideDuration prop. For instance, to
>   create a custom Notification component with a 5 seconds default:
>
> ```
> // in src/MyNotification.js
> import { Notification } from 'react-admin';
>
> const MyNotification = props => <Notification {...props}autoHideDuration={5000} />;
>
> export default MyNotification;
> ```

Comment: Hi, I need to customize notifications as my own .any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience it is necessary to write some functions and connect with react-admin

Answer (score 1):

`undoable` can only be set on `Edit` component and not on the `Create` component.

Handle the `formProps` coming from the Create page by adding a custom variable to check if the props are indeed from the 'Create' page or from the server.

To customize notification for `Create` or `Edit` page you can pass the `successMessage` prop to the components

```
successMessage="Item created successfully" //or use translate
```

[More about 'successMessage' can be found here - React Documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#success-message)

Answer (score 1):

With react-admin v.4 the way to disable Undo feature so changes are immediately saved is to add `mutationMode="optimistic"` to Edit/Create component.

To change the success notification message  use `mutationOptions={{ onSuccess }}` together with notify hook

```
    import { useNotify, useRefresh, useRedirect, Edit } from 'react-admin';

    const notify = useNotify();
    const refresh = useRefresh();
    const redirect = useRedirect();

    const onSuccess = () => {
        notify(`Changes saved`);
        redirect('/your-collection');
        refresh();
    };

    return (
        <Edit mutationMode="optimistic" mutationOptions={{ onSuccess }}>
        ...
```